# R matchingMarkets::hri() Error in x[y] : invalid subscript type 'list'

Tags: r, algorithm, graph, syntax-error, matching

I am trying to use the Gale-Shapely algorithm in R `matchingMarkets::hri()` to assign 10 students (A-J) to 6 groups (1-6) based on their preferences and subject to capacity constraints in each group. Each student ranks their top 3 choices for groups and all other choices are null. My issue is that

```
> hri(nSlots=capacities$capacity, s.prefs = student_prefs_matrix, c.prefs = null_matrix)
```

returns this:
   `Error in x[y] : invalid subscript type 'list'`

`hri()` does allow missing values, according to the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/matchingMarkets/matchingMarkets.pdf) (this is unlike the similar `matchingR::galeShapely.collegeAdmissions()`), so that is not where the issue lays. I compared my inputs to the example in the documentation (p. 7) and all same type of structure. Here are my inputs:

```
> student_prefs_matrix
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j
1  3  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
2 NA NA  3 NA NA  3  3  2  2  2
3 NA NA NA NA  1  2 NA NA  1  3
4  1  3 NA  3 NA NA NA NA NA NA
5 NA  2  2  1  3  1  1  1  3  1
6  2 NA  1  2  2 NA  2  3 NA NA


> null_matrix
   1  2  3  4  5  6
a NA NA NA NA NA NA
b NA NA NA NA NA NA
c NA NA NA NA NA NA
d NA NA NA NA NA NA
e NA NA NA NA NA NA
f NA NA NA NA NA NA
g NA NA NA NA NA NA
h NA NA NA NA NA NA
i NA NA NA NA NA NA
j NA NA NA NA NA NA

>  capacities$capacity
 [1] 2 2 2 2 1 1
```

Can anyone give a hint as to what this error may mean? The only list (vector) I give is for `nSlots` which is supposed to be a list. Alternatively, is there a better way to solve this matching problem? I know Gale Shapely is meant for 2 sided matchings but I thought this may work anyways if I always look for "student optimal" matching. Thanks for the help! This is my first time posting a question on here.

Answer (score 1):

To fix your problem, make sure to provide the preference lists in the appropriate format. See the documentation of the matchingMarkets package at https://matchingmarkets.org/hri.html for several examples on this.

Let us look at an example with 7 students, 2 colleges with 3 slots each, and given preference lists as follows:

```
> s.prefs <- matrix(c(1,2, 1,2, 1,NA, 1,2, 1,2, 1,2, 1,2), 2,7)
> c.prefs <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7, 1,2,3,4,5,NA,NA), 7,2)
> hri(s.prefs=s.prefs, c.prefs=c.prefs, nSlots=c(3,3))

> s.prefs
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2   NA    2    2   NA   NA

> c.prefs
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    2
[3,]    3    4
[4,]    4    5
[5,]    5   NA
[6,]    6   NA
[7,]    7   NA
```

For your specification of the preference lists, there are two problems. The most obvious problem is your `college_prefs_matrix` that currently indicates that none of the colleges find any student acceptable. Thus no stable matching can exist. The other problem is in your `student_prefs_matrix`. In your example, student `a` finds colleges `4`, `6`, and `1` acceptable (in that order). Thus the preference list should be:

```
> student_prefs_matrix
      a  b  c  d ...
[1,]  4  1  6  5 ...
[2,]  6  5  5  6 ...
[3,]  1  4  2  4 ...
[4,] NA NA NA NA ...
[5,] NA NA NA NA ...
[6,] NA NA NA NA ...
```